# Why non-root logger is not writing any log to log file?

Tags: python, file, logging, handlers

I want to write into two log files by using two loggers with following .ini config file:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,teja

[handlers]
keys=fileHandler,tejaFileHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_teja]
level=DEBUG
handlers=tejaFileHandler
qualname='tejaLogger'


[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=fileHandler

[handler_fileHandler]
class=logging.FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=("error.log", "a")

[handler_tejaFileHandler]
class=logging.FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=("teja.log", "a")

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

And I am using this configuration in my python code as

```
import logging
import logging.config
# load my module

import my_module

# load the logging configuration

logging.config.fileConfig('logging.ini')

logger1=logging.getLogger('root')
logger1.info('Hi how are you?')

logger2=logging.getLogger('teja')
logger2.debug('checking teja logger?')
```

I see that logs are written to error.log file whereas no logs are written to teja.log file. Please correct me if I am doing something silly...

Comment: will you please try `logger2.error`. If its write to `teja.log` then there might be level issue.

Comment: @Lafada: the log levels are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You named your logger object `'tejaLogger'`:

```
[logger_teja]
level=DEBUG
handlers=tejaFileHandler
qualname='tejaLogger'
#        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note that the *quotes are part of the name*.

but your test code picks up `teja` instead:

```
logger2=logging.getLogger('teja')
```

Rename one or the other; although you could use `logging.getLogger("'tejaLogger'")`
 you probably want to drop the quotes and / or rename the logger to what you expected it to be:

```
[logger_teja]
level=DEBUG
handlers=tejaFileHandler
qualname=teja
```

Comment: Yup, amusingly the logger is called `'tejaLogger'` by logging. I would've thought `.ini`s were more intelligent, but no...

Comment: @matsjoyce: the ini file requires the `qualname` field to name the logger, but the format doesn't require quoting (and single quotes are seen as part of the value)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem is on this line (in the `[logger_teja]` section):

```
qualname='tejaLogger'
```

If you add this to your code (it prints all the current loggers):

```
print(logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict)
```

You get:

```
{"'tejaLogger'": <logging.Logger object at 0x7f89631170b8>}
```

Which means that your logger is called literally `'tejaLogger'`. Using:

```
logger2=logging.getLogger("'tejaLogger'")`
```

Actually works fine. Either do that, or change `qualname='tejaLogger'` to `qualname=teja`.